# Combine list of dataframes into one dataframe and summarize in one step

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table, tidyverse

I want to combine/reduce a list of dataframes into one dataframe, but I also want to summarize the data in one step. The output is from a simulation; therefore, each dataframe has the same output structure (i.e., a Group column, then 2 columns with values, which will have values that vary for each output).

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(Group = c("A", "B", "C"), Top_Group = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), Efficiency = c(0.464688158128411, 0.652386676520109, 
0.282913417555392)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(Group = c("A", "B", "C"
), Top_Group = c(0L, 1L, 0L), Efficiency = c(0.120292583014816, 
0.0356206290889531, 0.37196880299598)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    Group = c("A", "B", "C"), Top_Group = c(0L, 1L, 0L), Efficiency = c(0.261322160949931, 
    0.383351784432307, 0.754808459430933)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

**What I Have Tried**

I know I could bind the data together, then group and summarize.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Top_Group = sum(Top_Group), Efficiency = max(Efficiency))

#  Group Top_Group Efficiency
#  <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
#1 A             1      0.465
#2 B             2      0.652
#3 C             0      0.755
```

I was hoping that there was someway to use something like `reduce`; however, I can only get it to work for pulling out one column (like `Top_Group` shown here), and am unsure how to use across all columns (if possible) and return a dataframe instead of vectors.

```
df_list %>%
  map(2) %>%
  reduce(`+`)

# [1] 1 2 0
```

**Expected Output**

```
  Group Top_Group Efficiency
  <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
1 A             1      0.465
2 B             2      0.652
3 C             0      0.755
```

Comment: Even though you are looking for a `reduce` solution, I'd say your current code is the most elegant/straightforward one IMO.

Comment: @deschen Thanks. I ended up doing a benchmark (below) to see what was quicker, and actually found that using `data.table` is actually the fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the OP's code, different functions were used on different columns.  So, we may have to individually apply those elementwise functions

```
library(purrr)
reduce(df_list, ~ tibble(.x[1], .x[2] + .y[2], pmax(.x[3], .y[3])))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Group Top_Group Efficiency
  <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
1 A             1      0.465
2 B             2      0.652
3 C             0      0.755
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Does `.x[2] + .y[2]` act as like a cumulative sum? I understand the `.x[]`, but trying to understand how the `.y[]` is used here.

Comment: @AndrewGB Yes, with `reduce`, we usually do `reduce(1:5, `+`)#
[1] 15` returns the cumulative and returns a single value as opposed to `accumulate`.  When we use lambda call, it will be the x, y, for the prev, current

Answer (score 4):

In base R you could just do

```r
Reduce(function(a, b) cbind(a[1], a[2] + b[2], pmax(a[3], b[3])), df_list)
#>   Group Top_Group Efficiency
#> 1     A         1  0.4646882
#> 2     B         2  0.6523867
#> 3     C         0  0.7548085
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution with `reduce`, `fulljoin`, and then a `rowwise` `summarize`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "Group") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  summarize(Group = Group,
            Top_Group  = sum(c_across(starts_with("Top_Group"))),
            Efficiency = max(c_across(starts_with("Efficiency")))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Group Top_Group Efficiency
  <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
1 A             1      0.465
2 B             2      0.652
3 C             0      0.755
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `aggregate` + `ave`

```
aggregate(
    . ~ Group,
    transform(
        do.call(
            rbind,
            df_list
        ),
        Efficiency = ave(
            Efficiency,
            Group,
            FUN = function(x) max(x) / length(x)
        )
    ), sum
)
```

or `aggregate` + `sapply`

```
transform(
    aggregate(. ~ Group, do.call(rbind, df_list), list),
    Top_Group = sapply(Top_Group, sum),
    Efficiency = sapply(Efficiency, max)
)
```

gives

```
  Group Top_Group Efficiency
1     A         1  0.4646882
2     B         2  0.6523867
3     C         0  0.7548085
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `data.table`, where we can use `rbindlist`, then summarize the columns.

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(df_list)[, list(Top_Group = sum(Top_Group),
                          Efficiency = max(Efficiency)), by = .(Group)]
```

**Output**

```
   Group Top_Group Efficiency
1:     A         1  0.4646882
2:     B         2  0.6523867
3:     C         0  0.7548085
```

**Benchmark**

Just out of curiosity (as this question is not about efficiency), I also ran all the current answers to see what is the fastest. The base R options are fast, but apparently the `data.table` option is the fastest.

[image]

*Code*

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(akrun = reduce(df_list, ~ tibble(.x[1], .x[2] + .y[2], pmax(.x[3], .y[3]))),
                                     AllanCameron = Reduce(function(a, b) cbind(a[1], a[2] + b[2], pmax(a[3], b[3])), df_list),
                                     ThomasIsCoding_agg_ave = {aggregate(
                                       . ~ Group,
                                       transform(
                                         do.call(
                                           rbind,
                                           df_list
                                         ),
                                         Efficiency = ave(
                                           Efficiency,
                                           Group,
                                           FUN = function(x) max(x) / length(x)
                                         )
                                       ), sum
                                     )},
                                     ThomasIsCoding_agg_sapply = {transform(
                                       aggregate(. ~ Group, do.call(rbind, df_list), list),
                                       Top_Group = sapply(Top_Group, sum),
                                       Efficiency = sapply(Efficiency, max)
                                     )
                                       },
                                     deschen = df_list %>%
                                       reduce(full_join, by = "Group") %>%
                                       rowwise() %>%
                                       summarize(Group = Group,
                                                 Top_Group  = sum(c_across(starts_with("Top_Group"))),
                                                 Efficiency = max(c_across(starts_with("Efficiency")))) %>%
                                       ungroup(),
                                     TomHoel = df_list %>% 
                                       tibble() %>%
                                       unnest(cols = c(.)) %>% 
                                       group_by(Group) %>%  
                                       summarise(Top_Group = sum(Top_Group), Efficiency = max(Efficiency)),
                                     AndrewGB_tidyverse = df_list %>% 
                                       bind_rows() %>%
                                       group_by(Group) %>%
                                       summarise(Top_Group = sum(Top_Group), Efficiency = max(Efficiency)),
                                     AndrewGB_datatable = rbindlist(df_list)[, list(Top_Group = sum(Top_Group), Efficiency = max(Efficiency)), by=.(Group)],
                                     times = 2000
                                     )
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it! Check out `?unnest()`

```
require(tidyverse)

df_list %>% 
  tibble() %>%
  unnest(cols = c(.)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%  
  summarise(Top_Group = sum(Top_Group), Efficiency = max(Efficiency))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Group Top_Group Efficiency
  <chr>     <int>      <dbl>
1 A             1      0.465
2 B             2      0.652
3 C             0      0.755
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R, a few months late:

```
subset(
  within(
    do.call(rbind, df_list),
    {
      Top_Group <- ave(Top_Group, Group, FUN = sum)
      Efficiency <- ave(Efficiency, Group, FUN = max)
    }
  ),
  !(duplicated(Group))
)
```